# How to have custom component as title of NavBar in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-router-flux

By default, I can only have a single line of text in the title of the NavBar with react-native-router-flux.

I want to have 2 lines of text in the title of the NavBar. Thus, how can I actually have a custom component as the title of the NavBar in react-native-router-flux?

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [documentation](http://%20https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API_CONFIGURATION.md), you can pass a custom NavBar to your Scene or Router.

```
 <Scene key="about" component={AboutScreen} navBar={()=>{return <CustomNavBar/>} />
```

Unfortunately, you cannot have a custom NavBar Title, so you have to create a whole NavBar if you really need this functionality.

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Problem with creating an entirely custom NavBar is that I will lose all that standard functionalities such as back arrow, slide-fade transition animation when being dragged or navigated, etc, in my custom NavBar. :(

Comment: Yeah, true.. in this case I would recommend you to modify the library and try to do a PR, I'd even do it by myself if I wasn't too busy. The other solution is to create a custom component and place it right below the title, which is more of a hack rather than a solution. Either way, good luck!